# Reponse.cookies not working after migrating an ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

After migrating Asp.Net Core 2.2 to 3.1 the object Response is no found anymore to work with Cookies.

[CookieService](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8NeZ.png)

Comment: Hi @Jd3,I could not get the Response object even in asp.net core 2.2.The default Response object is in `ControllerBase`.Please share the code instead of screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this may fix it.

```
CookieOptions
            {
                Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
                **IsEssential = true**
            }
```